# Magento 2 About Us Layout

Tags: php, html, magento2

We want to edit the left part of the page layout of about us as seen in the photo, we want to remove the "compare" part and customize it. Where can we edit it?

[image: see image]

Answer (score 0):

For this functionality i see you're using layout `2columns-left`
To edit this functionality in magento you can do it by updating the layout file for your page.

You can remove this part of the page by using this xml handle in your xml config:

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
```

After you have removed compare from left sidebar you can create your own block and assign it to left sidebar using this command

```
<referenceBlock name="left">
     <block name="your.custom.block.name" class="Vendor\Module\Block\YourBlock" template="Vendor\Module::template.phtml" />
</referenceBlock>
```

These two command layouts updates will do:

- First one will remove the compare products from sidebar
- Second one will add your custom block to the sidebar, where you can put code you need to

Only thing you should be carefull to put this is on right layout handle.
The handle for this will lay in your module: Vendor\YourModule\view\frontend\layout
In case that you showed here it would be
`cms_tmt_about_us.xml`
Please check this in your configuration that this is the right handle

Comment: You add your custom block in the same layout handle. In case of what i made as an example is cms_tmt_about_us.xml, using the second snippet of code i've provided

Comment: Just be sure that the class of the block element is your module class name

Comment: sort of. i managed to remove the the compare part but not yet adding my customized block

Comment: Hmmmm can you share the code you use for this handle

Comment: actually, i cant add my custom block because i cant find the file path of the layout handle and im editing on the magento admin side. i hope i can just edit it there..

Comment: Go to the about us page in content management. Edit it and go to Design > Layout Update XML. But if you can't access the code you will have problems because you need to create that block by code, to have your custom code in it